# How to track down "Dynamic requires are not currently supported by rollup-plugin-commonjs" error?

Tags: commonjs, rollup

I'm getting "Dynamic requires are not currently supported by rollup-plugin-commonjs" error in the runtime when I bundle and run my actual application. However, I can't understand what causes this error.

I tried everything I could think of to reproduce the issue but I'm unable to do so. Here is [my best attempt](https://github.com/ceremcem/debug-ls/tree/fb57594b7ded076123610f1a36ccc73fc8838c01/example/dynamic-require) to reproduce:

in `my_node_modules/my-lib.ls`:

```
some-state = Math.random() >= 0.5
if some-state
    require! './hey'
...
```

According to my knowledge (if I'm not wrong) this is absolutely a dynamic require which the requirement is decided in the runtime. However, rollup does not complain about it.

[`package.json` is here](https://github.com/ceremcem/debug-ls/blob/fb57594b7ded076123610f1a36ccc73fc8838c01/package.json#L20-L27) and my rollup version is 2.26.8.

Here is [my actual application](https://github.com/ceremcem/chibios-configurator/blob/c3792cc6b498f5010a9133f448f18371340cc0d4/servers/stm/template.ls) and here is [the bundled version](https://gist.github.com/f378161ac6a3c9a224567b6e06c7080c).

#### Expected Behavior

An error to be thrown indicating the responsible file for "Dynamic requires are not currently supported by rollup-plugin-commonjs" error.

#### Actual Behavior

Only the "Dynamic requires are not currently supported by rollup-plugin-commonjs" error is thrown, no clue for responsible file.

Answer (score 0):

Current version of `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` (mine is now `15.0.0`) points the problematic file.

Credit: https://github.com/rollup/plugins/issues/562#issuecomment-685922475